# change loss function during training

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

Suppose my loss function is of the following form:

loss = a*loss_1 + (1-a)*loss_2

Suppose also I am training for 100 steps.  How can I dynamically change the loss function in tensorflow so that I gradually change "a" from 1 to 0 during the 100 steps of training?

To be precise, I want my loss to be
 loss = 1*loss_1+0*loss_2 = loss_1 
at the beginning of training (at step 1)

and

loss = 0*loss_1+1*loss_2 = loss_2 at the end (step 100)

with some kind of gradual (doesn't have to be continuous) decrease in between.

Comment: I realize a really hacky solution would be to train with loss_1 for the first 50 steps, and then remember the weights of that training and then retrain with loss_2 for the remaining steps.  However I am looking for a way to do this without having to make two graphs, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value of `a` does not depend on the computation done at the current step, create a placeholder for `a` then pass the value you want using the feed dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.train.polynomial_decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/polynomial_decay).

```
tf.train.polynomial_decay(learning_rate=1, global_step=step_from_placeholder,
    decay_steps=100, end_learning_rate=0,
    power=1.0, cycle=False, name=None)
```

This computes

```
global_step = min(global_step, decay_steps)
decayed_learning_rate = (learning_rate - end_learning_rate) * \
  (1 - global_step / decay_steps) ** (power) + end_learning_rate
```